# Angular/Typescript interface and implementing class: Attributes with `@, $` characters in them

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-class

I am following the approach of JHipster in my Angular app, which I believe is pretty much best-practice based. As far as models are concerned, this is how they are doing it:

```
export interface IPerson {
  id: number;
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

export class Person implements IPerson {

  constructor(
    public id: number,
    public firstName: string,
    public lastName: string) {}

}
```

I encountered the problem when I tried to add the following attribute (dictated by the third-party API that I'm using and there are many other that contain another special characters, such as `$` etc.):

```
export interface IPerson {
  ...
  '@type': string; // here it's ok
}

export class Person implements IPerson {

  constructor(
    ...
    // here, however, the compiler goes 
    // nuts, showing it in red and underlined
    public '@type': string
}
```

So, it seems it's not the usage in a class itself that is problematic, but rather the usage in the constructor, declaring it this way.

Does anyone have an idea how to at least work around this?

Comment: Why are you using `public '@type': string` in the constructor?

Comment: Because I thought I should initialize it in constructor just like other attributes from the interface. Is there another way?

Comment: you can initialize it outside the constructor as a class variable too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is "best practice", but if you want to assign all the properties in the constructor then you simply have to choose another name for the constructor parameters.

```
class Person implements IPerson {
    '@type': string;
    constructor(type: string, public name: string) {
        this['@type'] = type;
    }
}
```

However, if `Person` doesn't get any behaviour attached, I don't see much value in creating a class at all. I would just do

```
const person: IPerson = { '@type': 'some_type', name: 'developer10' };
```

I would even say that constructors with long list of arguments are 'bad practice'...

```
const person = new Person('this', 'that', 'first', 'last); // is that the correct order i dunno..
```